# Unity, Kudan: How to use usb camera for tracking on android

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I've googled about using usb camera for tracking marker on android (kudan plugin) but did not find any answer.
Can you tell me how to do this?
Sorry about my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kudan framework doesn't currently support USB cameras through Android. You should raise a feature request with Kudan for adding this.